# Run a Command in terminal with HTTP API

Tags: api, terminal

I need to make a remote API to exec a command in a Linux terminal
How can we create this system?
For example:
90.100.24.146:8080/run?cmd=echo+hello

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us which programming language you prefer in order to create your API.

If you use PHP, you can take benefit of the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. So when you send your HTTP request, your web server will catch it and make it correspond to a route defined in your API. Then you will get the request parameters and use the **exec** function with the command specified in your request. It is also easy to create a short API with Symfony and you can use the [Symfony Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) which wrap the **exec** PHP function.

It is just an example to explain how to proceed to achieve your goal whatever programming language you use.